# Efficient way to discretize continous functions in Python

Tags: python, performance

I want to discretize continous functions in Python where I can arbitrarily set a discretization strength `eta`. In my current implementation there is not discretization at all if `eta` goes to infinity. Here are two examples with `eta = 5`.

[image]
[image]

I would like to know if there is a much better way to discretize a continous function in Python? Maybe there is a Numpy implementation of such a function which I currently don't know of which is much faster. Right now the implementation below is a bottleneck in my code.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def continous2discrete(x, eta):
    return (x*eta).astype(np.int).astype(np.double) / eta

def main():
    x = np.linspace(-2,2,1000);
    plt.plot(x,np.sin(np.pi*x))
    y = continous2discrete(np.sin(np.pi*x), eta=5)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Consider posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: `.astype(np.int).astype(np.double)` I can't think of any reason for this. A "poor man's" rounding?

Comment: @roganjosh You are right! I should probably work with `np.round()` instead. Thanks for pointing that out for me!

Comment: @Samuel More like `np.trunc()` — `np.round()` rounds to the next _even_ value.